# F# Discriminated union with optional recurcive component

Tags: functional-programming, f#, optional-parameters, discriminated-union

I'm working with F# and I struggle building my business model.
Let's say I have a list of float and two types of transformations I can apply on it.
By example:

type Transformation =
| SMA of period:Period
| P2MA of period:Period

Then I have defined a function `let compute Transformation list` to compute any kind of transformation over a list.

With the above Transformation type, I can create a SMA(3) or a P2SMA(5) by example.

I would like to be able to nest the transformations in a way I can write SMA(3, P2SMA(5, SMA(10))) by example. But also I would like to still be able to write SMA(2) only.
I tried using options, but I think writing SMA(3, None) or SMA(3, Some(P2SMA(5))) is too verbose.

Is there any way to do that? Maybe my approach is wrong, as I'm new in F#, I may tackle the problem by the wrong way?

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to model, I understand you have 2 transformation types that map a list of floats to? ...a list of floats?..I can't see why you'd need to nest them, rather than just have a list of transformations that you apply (in order)?

Comment: I don't really need to nest them. I'm transposing a code I have written in C# to F#. In my C# code I'm able to nest them thanks to constructor overloading and I just find it elegant to write a nested transformation as SMA(3, P2SMA(5)) by example. The question was if there is a way (and it is suitable ) to do the same in F#. Actually, thanks to your remarks and other answers, I realize this is not the way to go. And simply chaining them in a array [SMA(3), P2SMA(5)] and then piping the computation of each transfo seems the simplest and cleanest functional solution. Thanks

Comment: I like your conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Try my answer here.](https://try.fsharp.org/#?code=C4TwDgpgBAChBOBLA9gEygXiogdsAsAFBGiRQDKAtgIYAq81OAzgGbLyWZFQ9QA+FGlGQtYCFKm68BVagHJhouEjRQAVFHqNW7SkSKN0MAExMaW5mw5dCvfrFNCRYlZNvSHZ+YpcT1mhktdfUJDAO0rTgwpHgEAeRZZH1kLHQ4Y+wSTJOcTL1TIkIAbCGAKAFkAQQAKSFcAShs7WVrxNEa+AD4oBNli0orKuVbXABooYEC0ykbo9x5ZYbqJccmI3Q7u3pp+suyqkYlZjLyaQ-b+LZZsneJCEr3jciqlttRVqcjj+c8aV7GJp8NpcetcnrciA9AesOEwmrwANp8DLNA4AZnqKN4+xqAFZMT9UUNqmjxjjhrjxs8agBGAAM9UZGT4AF0QlZoUFrLhOdM4ahkBkwEg8CwcFAAEQAUkqEt5hUIQA&html=DwCwLgtgNgfAsAKAAQqaApgQwCb2ag4CdMTJcMABwFp0BHAVwEsA3AXgCIBhAewDsw6AdQAqAT0roOSAMb9BAzoIAeYAPThoAbhkhMAJwDOJNgzAAzagA4OeQhqy5EhAEY9sYu6mBq3HvD6asEA&css=Q)

It's not possible to overload discriminated union cases in exactly the way you want. But if you'll accept a very slightly different syntax, you could do this instead:

```ml
type Period = int

type SmaTransform =
    | Sma of Period
    | Sma' of Period * Transform

and P2smaTransform =
    | P2sma of Period
    | P2sma' of Period * Transform

and Transform =
    | OfSma of SmaTransform
    | OfP2Sma of P2smaTransform

let SMA(period) =
    Sma(period) |> OfSma

let SMA'(period, transform) =
    Sma'(period, transform) |> OfSma

let P2SMA(period) =
    P2sma(period) |> OfP2Sma

let P2SMA'(period, transform) =
    P2sma'(period, transform) |> OfP2Sma

let transforms =
    [|
        SMA(3)
        P2SMA(5)
        SMA'(3, P2SMA'(5, SMA(10)))
    |]

for transform in transforms do
    printfn "%A" transform
```

The only difference from your desired syntax is the apostrophe that denotes a nested transform.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried using options, but I think writing SMA(3, None) or SMA(3, Some(P2SMA(5))) is too verbose.

You can use a static member with an optional argument:

```ml
type Transformation =
    | [<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>]
      SMAInternal of period:int * inner: Transformation option
    ...
    static member SMA(period:int, ?t:Transformation) =
        SMAInternal(period, t)
```

You can then write: `Transformation.SMA(3)` or `Transformation.SMA(3, Transformation.P2SMA(5))`. This takes more characters but has fewer constructs. You may or may not regard it as more concise.

> I'm new in F#, I may tackle the problem by the wrong way?

If you are going to be defining hundreds of these things in a code file then using the above approach and shortening the name `Transformation` may be a good idea. Otherwise just use the Somes and Nones. Verbosity is a negligible consideration and if you start to worry about it, horrible things start happening.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand quite what you're trying to model, but here is something hopefully similar.

My Transformations are either multiple a number or add to it

```
type Trans = 
    | Mult of period: int
    | Add of period: int
```

and I can now write an interpret function, that given a number and a transformation, I can interpret it

```
let interpret x trans = 
    match trans with
    | Mult p -> p * x
    | Add p -> p + x
```

so we can now do simple
let x = interpret 1 (Mult 2)

but you want to chain transformations?
so lets allow that..

```
let interprets xs x = 
    List.fold (fun state trans -> 
        interpret state trans) x xs
```

and we can go...

```
let foo = [ Mult 3; Add 2 ]

let bar = interprets foo 1
```

OK, so IF you really want to deal with these compositions of lists of transformations uniformly, which may be nice (a bit like function composition).

Then i would be tempted to go (note I'm trying to follow your coding style)
(there's quite a lot to take in here, so maybe stick with the above approach until you're happy you understand F# a bit better).

```
type Trans = 
    | Mult of period: int
    | Add of period: int
    | Compose of chain: List<Trans>
 
let rec interpret x trans = 
    let interprets xs x = 
        List.fold (fun state trans -> 
            interpret state trans) x xs
    match trans with
    | Mult p -> p * x
    | Add p -> p + x
    | Compose ps -> 
        interprets ps x
        
let two = interpret 1 (Mult 2)

let three = interpret 1 (Compose [ Mult 2; Add 1 ])
```

Now I think you have a data model that "works", and is pretty simple.

I wouldnt then try to change the data model to make your code convenient, I'd create utility functions to do that (smart constructors) to do that.

e.g.

```
let multThen x trans = Compose [ Mult x; trans ]
let addThen x trans = Compose [ Add x; trans ]
```

The advice though is to make the data model model the data in the simplest manner, and then use functions to make your code elegant, and map in and out of that model, often the two things look quite different.

Caveat: I havent tested some of this code